# Is there a name for the gesture Buddy Christ is doing?

Tags: gestures

Is there a name, term, or idiom for this gesture, the one buddy christ is doing here? Or a name similar to this gesture?

[image]

Comment: It's the "I see what you did there" gesture! :)

Answer (score 4):

***Point and wink*** comes pretty close ([here](http://www.google.com/search?q=point+and+wink&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi96OmEzZTLAhUBZCYKHWbJA6QQ_AUIBygB&biw=356&bih=569.3333333333334&dpr=1.5)), but doesn't get you the thumbs up. In fact, the image you posted shows up in that search result.

A related gesture is ***finger guns***, which is usually playful and positive and often accompanied by a wink ([here](http://www.google.com/search?q=finger+guns&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2t__SzpTLAhWJPiYKHThOARkQ_AUIBygB&biw=356&bih=569.3333333333334&dpr=1.5)).

In fact, if you google image search "Jesus finger guns", you'll get a lot of results showing the image of Buddy Christ.

Comment: Along with "finger guns", "double guns"

Comment: Although it's also true that a "finger gun" has gotten at least one child suspended from school in the US.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a single term for this. Rather, it's two gestures combined:

• Pointing and winking, indicating a personal or covert understanding

• "Thumbs up", indicating approval